# java regex pattern matching vs schema validation

Tags: java, regex, xsd

Please consider the regex pattern : `.*[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_].*`.
If I use **Java** regex pattern matching to match `"-"`, it says it is *true*.

```
String regexCostcode1=".*[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_].*";
Pattern regex_costcode=Pattern.compile(regexCostcode1);
String test="-";
Matcher m = regex_costcode.matcher(test);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

This prints *true*. 
But same regex fails for `"-"` in **XSD schema validation**.

I checked using http://regexr.com/ it fails to match `"-"`.

So why it is matching using **Java** pattern matching?

Answer (score 2):

Mind that in a Java string literal you need 2 backslashes to define a literal backslash. When you use `\\` at the regexr.com, or in XML Schema regex, you use 2 literal backslashes that match a literal backslash in the input string, and the `[\\-\\]` construct matches a single `\`.

In XML Schema, you need to define the regex as

```
<xs:pattern value=".*[a-zA-Z0-9_-].*"/>
```

Put the `-` at the end of the character class to be parsed as a literal `-`. The underscore does not need to be escaped at all, as it is never a special char (it is actually a "word" char).

Actually, I'd advise to use `".*[a-zA-Z0-9_-].*"` in Java, too, to avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: I can not change the regex .*[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_].* in schema. I need to change it in Java. What should i use in Java

Comment: See my last line in the answer.

Comment: If you want to return false in Java when a string contains `-`, you need to remove it - `String regexCostcode1=".*[a-zA-Z0-9_].*";`, or even use a mere `String regexCostcode1=".*\\w.*";` (or a more efficient and safe `"(?s)\\W*\\w.*"`).

Answer (score 1):

For non-Java regexes you don't need to use double back-slashes. So your regex should be `.*[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_].*` in Java and `.*[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_].*` in XSD schema validation.

If you input `.*[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\_].*` in the site you mentioned, it tells you that `\\-\\` is being interpreted as a "range of characters from \ to \" since `\\` is just an escaped back-slash.
If you input `.*[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_].*` it interprets `\-` as just an escaped hypen and correctly matches `-`.